# Adding a Video using jPCT-AE and Vuforia SDK

Tags: android, vuforia, jpct

I'm trying to build an AR Android app that uses Vuforia + jPCT-AE.

The jPCT is being used because it makes it easier to use objects exported from Blender, and dramatically reduces the code verbosity (when compared with vuforia stand-alone).

I would like to introduce the possibility to display a video along with different objects (e.g. a banana and a monkey ) that were rendered using jPCT-AE, however I haven't found any clues (documentation) on how to do this so I'm asking for you help and knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use of vuforia video playback in this [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples):

> *Advanced Topics*
>
> The samples below show how to implement sophisticated rendering techniques in Unity and OpenGL ES to enrich your app with creative effects. A project to show you how to work with C++ on Android is also available.
>
> - ...
> - Video Playback